# How to join on two xml fields with unknown parameter names at design time

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I have two tables that need to be joined based on matching xml.  The use of xml is because unknown set of values at design time.  I have written up a 3 senarios in below.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

**TableA**
Id
xml

**Table B**
Id
xml

**Table A**
1, `<parms><parm><name>Parm1</name><value>X</value></parm></parms>`
2, `<parms><parm><name>Parm1</name><value>Y</value></parm>

           <parm><name>Parm2</name><value>123</value></parm></parms>

3, <parms><parm><name>Parm1</name><value>Y</value></parm>

          <parm><name>Parm2</name><value>578</value></parm></parms>`

Table B
7, `<parms><parm><name>Parm1</name><value>X</value></parm></parms>`
8, `<parms><parm><name>Parm1</name><value>Y</value></parm>

          <parm><name>Parm2</name><value>123</value></parm></parms>`
9, `<parms><parm><name>Parm1</name><value>Y</value></parm>

          <parm><name>Parm2</name><value>123</value></parm>

          <parm><name>Parm2</name><value>578</value></parm></parms>`

Query Something like this but I need help with the join.

```
select A.Id  
     , B.Id  
  from TableA A  
 inner join TableB B  
    on ???
```

Expected Results

```
A.Id   B.Id  
1       7  
2       8  
3       8  
3       9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @TableA table (id int, xmlCol xml)
declare @TableB table (id int, xmlCol xml)

insert into @TableA values
(1, '<parms><parm><name>Parm1</name><value>X</value></parm></parms>'),
(2, '<parms><parm><name>Parm1</name><value>Y</value></parm>
<parm><name>Parm2</name><value>123</value></parm></parms>'),
(3, '<parms><parm><name>Parm1</name><value>Y</value></parm>
<parm><name>Parm2</name><value>578</value></parm></parms>')

insert into @TableB values
(7, '<parms><parm><name>Parm1</name><value>X</value></parm></parms>'),
(8, '<parms><parm><name>Parm1</name><value>Y</value></parm>
<parm><name>Parm2</name><value>123</value></parm></parms>'),
(9, '<parms><parm><name>Parm1</name><value>Y</value></parm>
<parm><name>Parm2</name><value>123</value></parm>
<parm><name>Parm2</name><value>578</value></parm></parms>')

;with cteA as
(
  select 
    A.id,
    p.value('name[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Name,
    p.value('value[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Value
  from @TableA as A
    cross apply A.xmlCol.nodes('parms/parm') as n(p)
), cteB as
(
  select 
    B.id,
    p.value('name[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Name,
    p.value('value[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Value
  from @TableB as B
    cross apply B.xmlCol.nodes('parms/parm') as n(p)
)
select distinct
  A.id as 'A.id',
  (select top 1 B.id
   from cteB as B
   where B.Name = B.Name and
         B.Value = A.Value
   order by B.id asc) as 'B.id'
from cteA as A
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: Thanks Mikael.  Sorry for not awarding you the answer sooner.  Your answer led me to my final solution.  I remember banging my head then your answer shed the light.  You Rock!